# How to draw an irregular loop in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

I'm trying to illustrate a sensor network inside a domain. This is what I have right now:

[image]

Here is the code I used to generate this:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \foreach \i /\x/\y in {
            1/1/1.7320508075689,
            2/-1/1.7320508075689,
            3/-2/0,
            4/-1/-1.7320508075689,
            5/1/-1.7320508075689,
            6/2/0,
            7/4/0,
            8/4.7/0.6,
            9/4.7/-0.6
        }{
            \node [coordinate] (n\i) at (\x,\y) {\i};
        }

        \foreach \i in {1,...,9} {
            \fill (n\i) circle (1pt);
            \fill [orange,opacity=0.3] (n\i) circle (1.4142135623731);
            %\draw [red] (n\i) circle (1);
            %\draw [green] (n\i) circle (3.1622776601684);
        }
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

and what I would like to achieve is something that has this on top:

[image]

Would anyone have any advice on doing something like this?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please add the code that you used to create this figure to the question.

Comment: Since there are no regularities I guess the only way is to draw curves by specifying coordinates you want them to pass..

Comment: Welcome to [TeX.SX](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)! Please help us (and also you) and add a minimal working example ([MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that)), that illustrates your problem. Reproducing your code will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass` and ending with `\end{document}`. It would be great if you add.

Comment: I can't see `\documentclass` and `\end{document}` in the question. But you already answered as well.

Comment: You're right indeed, I'll make an edit to order things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I see no other ways than drawing it by yourself with the `calc` library and the curve line tool for `\draw` command. Here I post just the partial work, you can imagine how to continue, also depending on where you want you curve to pass.

Here I just used the `out` `in` options which are explained in the [tikz documentation](https://www.bu.edu/math/files/2013/08/tikzpgfmanual.pdf) (p. 101):

> [...] if you write (a) to [out=135,in=45] (b) a curve is added to
>   the path, which leaves at an angle of 135◦ at a and arrives at an
>   angle of 45◦ at b. This is because the options in and out trigger a
>   special path to be used instead of the straight line [...]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}

    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \def\radius{1.4142135623731}
        \def\posyA{1.7320508075689}
        \def\posyB{0}
        \def\posyC{0.6}

        \foreach [count=\i] \x/\y in {%
            1/\posyA,
            -1/\posyA,
            -2/\posyB,
            -1/-\posyA,
            1/-\posyA,
            2/\posyB,
            4/\posyB,
            4.7/\posyC,
            4.7/-\posyC}{%
                \node [coordinate] (n\i) at (\x,\y) {\i};
                \fill (n\i) circle (1pt);
                \fill [orange, opacity=0.3] (n\i) circle (\radius);
                }
        \draw[blue, thick] ($(n2) + (0, 1)$) to[out=180, in=180] ($(n4) - (.5, 1)$)
            to[out=0, in=250] ($(n5) + (1, -.5)$)
            to[out=0, in=250] ($(n5) + (1, -.5)$);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

## OUTPUT

[image: The output]

Comment: This method will certainly do! Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer!

Comment: Oh, and I recommend to use the option `count` in the`foreach` in order not to have to re-write all the times 1/, 2/, 3/ and so on!

Comment: @FloydEverest if you are happy with this solution consider choosing best answer `;)`, you just need to click on the green check just above the voting symbols.